# Flot data variables from onclick ()

Tags: javascript, variables, asp-classic, flot

I have an asp page set up with a table of data. I have added a javascript function which gets data from the table and passes the values through to a second ASP page.

The second page contains a FLOT chart where I want to use the data. I am writing the values I am passing through out within my function but when I refresh the graph the data is missing. Almost like it cannot read the data I am passing through.

Does anyone know the best way to handle variables within FLOT? Or if there are any specific locations i need to be defining my variables?

My original datasource is an MS-access database (company limitations).

Comment: Is there any code you can post for us, so we can help you better?

Comment: Hi megan,See tue below code. Were passing the values (lw, week1, week2) into the function. Then when were defining our data (d1) and writing our variables out its taking them as null

Comment: Sorry its nit letting me post the code.

Comment: function GraphData(lw,week1,week2)

{

 

        //Bookstock

        var d1 = [

                [0, lw],

                [1, week1],

                [2, week2],

                [3, 767724832.3],

                [4, 773929999.5],

                [5, 796465617.4],

                [6, 788485234.4],

                [7, 790582043.8],

                [8, 771270929],

                [9, 754096499],

                [10, 754066499],

                [11, 754696499]

        ];

Comment: I then proceed to weite the flot chart options out. Its strange if I define a variable above I.e. apple =30. Then where I am defining d1 above writin out [0, apple], etc actually works

Comment: I don't understand your question and the snippet of a commented out function doesn't clarify anything.  You get the data from a table using javascript, you then "pass the values" to a second page. How?  A second page would require a request back to the server.  Are you passing the data in a post request or something?  Please try to add enough code to reproduce your problem.  As it stands now it's un-answerable and I'm voting to close.

Comment: How are you passing the data to the next page?

Answer (score 0):

Appologies we had a min set  with in the flot data which was overstating the bar.